# Does this code with nested Futures create a deadlock?

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool, future

Suppose I've got an `ExecutionContext` backed a fixed thread pool and function `foo`, which creates two nested Futures.

```
import scala.concurrent._

implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(...))
def foo(): Future[Int] = new Future {
  ...
  new Future { ... }
}
```

I guess this code may create a *deadlock* when `foo` creates many `Futures` that take all the threads and then get stuck because they cannot create the second nested `Future`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Creating the future doesn't really mean it will start right away. In this case, the executor will just wait for outer future to complete, then it will start inner. I will create deadlock only if you will explicitly block and wait for inner future with `Await.result`.

Comment: You are right: `foo` is not stuck. However suppose  we have function `bar` waiting for results of `foo`: `def bar(){ Await.result(foo(), Duration.Inf) }`. Would it  be stuck forever ?

Comment: `bar` outside `foo`? According [scala-lang](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#execution-context) "it is free to execute computations in a new thread, in a pooled thread or in the current thread (although executing the computation in the current thread is discouraged – more on that below)."

Comment: Suppose `bar` is running outside of `foo` on a separate thread. Would it be stuck forever waiting for `foo` future result ?

Comment: yes, if `foo` waiting infinite. I think this problem is different with inline future.

Comment: Well, now I think `bar` won't be waiting forever :) The inner future will be started waiting for a thread in a queue (or fail if the queue is full) then the outer future will complete and return its thread to the pool ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all `Future`s run to completion without blocking then there can be no deadlock.

If the code inside a `Future` is going to block it should be inside a `blocking` statement. This will create a new thread to prevent thread starvation of the original thread pool.

If a `Future` waits for the results that will be generated by another `Future` then there is the potential for deadlock.

Comment: Can you give an example of a deadlock when a future waits for the results of another _not nested_ future ?